# Forcing TabPanel to use specified TabItem template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

So I have created my own `TabControl` and `TabItem` templates (both with `x:Name` attribute), and I use them like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyTabControl}" />
    </Style>
```

As expected, this makes all `TabControl`s in the window use `MyTabControl` template, however it still uses the old `TabItem` template. How can I make it work so the code above somehow manages to style every `TabItem` inside that template to use `MyTabItem` template?

Of course I could just edit the `MyTabControl` template and set the template manually, but that would require me to use something else than `TabPanel` container (probably `StackPanel`). Is it somehow possible to tell the `TabPanel` to use specific template for every `TabItem`?

In `MyTabControl` I use this to display `TabItem`s:

```
<TabPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
```

And I'm looking for something like this (I don't know if this is possible):

```
<TabPanel IsItemsHost="True" TabItemsTemplate="MyTabItem" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would work:
Create a style for your TabItem, that sets it's Template to your TabItem Template

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabItemStyle" TargetType={x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TabItemTemplateName}" /> 
</Style>
```

and alter your above Style to:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl">
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyTabControl}" />
   <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyTabItemStyle}" />
</Style>
```

You could also just ignore the above and create a style without a key for your TabItem, and this will set all TabItems to this style.

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TabItemTemplateName}" /> 
</Style>
```

You could also have a look here:
http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/01/25/TabControlStyling_PartOne.aspx